# TFS2010: Output Directory of completed build

Tags: msbuild, macros

I'm trying to get the path to the final output directory where the assemblies are copied to.
For example: C:\Builds\My_Task\My_Build.DATE.BUILDNUMBER
(After a finished build, everything is located here)

Each of the macros $(OutDir) and $(TargetDir) points to a Directory called:
C:\Builds\1\WorkspaceName\My_Task\Binaries

Does such a macro that points to the first described location exists? Or how can I get that path into a macro so that I can use it in my msbuild-scripts?

---

So I finally got around my Problem, but I didn't found a way to get the real drop location directly into an msbuild-Skript.

I found the following question, and editing the Build-Process template works fine:
[How can I get TFS 2010 to build each project to a separate directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784335/how-can-i-get-tfs-2010-to-build-each-project-to-a-separate-directory)

Comment: How does your system end up having C:\Builds\My_Task\My_Build.DATE.BUILDNUMBER? Is that your drop location? Is is hard-coded in MSBuild project files?

Comment: I don`t know for sure. The last part (with date and build number) is configured in my build definition. I don`t know where the rest of the path comes from. (Maybe that Path is called the drop location - obviously I'm new to TeamBuild/msbuild)

Comment: Should it be considered as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784335/how-can-i-get-tfs-2010-to-build-each-project-to-a-separate-directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the $(DropLocation) macro to point to C:\Builds\My_Task\My_Build.DATE.BUILDNUMBER and see how that works out for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the $(DropLocation) macro doesn't work. If I try to use it in my msbuild-scripts (aka. Project-Files), it just resolves to an empty string.