# Visual Studio 2017 -TFS - Organise folder structure output

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, xamlbuild, build-templates

I'd like to organise my file in the same structure that it is built:

- Solution1

  - project1
  - project2

Currently I dealt with the output path of each project (..\bin\NameProject) to have this:

- Solution1

  - project1
  - project2

But in each project (so in project1 and project2), I find all the DLLs/executables from all projects.
I want that the output of project1 receives only DLLs/executable from project1, the same thing for project2.

Then, I think to fix that with build process template (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551(v=vs.120).aspx), so I have this structure:

- *BuildProcessTemplate

  - -BuildProcessSource

    - Templates (with my CustomTemplate.xaml inside)
- Solution1

  - -project1
  - -project2

But I don't know how this step could help me. Maybe it's not the good way. 
Do you have an idea?

Thank you for helping me!

**EDIT**

What I want as ouput exactly for instance:

```
Solution1
  project1
     including all output (DLLs) from project 1
  project2
     including all output (DLLs) from project 2
```

Comment: What's the purpose? You need because you have different versions of the same Assembly or to simply collecting Artifacts? What have you tried for the **Output Location** setting?

Comment: I edit my first message, for each project I have as output path:..\bin\nameProject\ (with the proper project name of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to customize your build process template. You could add this MSBuild parameter in your build definition and have a try. For more detail, please refer to [this blog](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2014/08/22/Separate-TFS-Build-Server-Output-into-Different-Folders.aspx).

```
 /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=True
```

And the Output Location still set to SingleFolder.
[image]

Here is another case which have the similar question with you, you could also refer to those replies in this link. [What's the best way to get TFS to output each project to its own directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698855/whats-the-best-way-to-get-tfs-to-output-each-project-to-its-own-directory)